# XPath, filter based on related nodes in

Tags: xpath

I've read about everything I can find and haven't found a way to get this to work. I'm trying to query for a sum from specific nodes based on values of the node or its parent. Some of the nodes may meet the basic requirements of having the proper name but their parent may not so I need to ignore those. In SQL terms I would approach this with an EXISTS or LIKE clause.

What I'm trying to do is

```
   SUM    ServiceAmounts 
   FROM   ChargeData elements 
   WHERE  ChargeDescription = 'subTotal-DistrubutionCharges' 
          AND Detail.ServiceType = 'electric' 
          AND NOT 
          (
              ChargeData has a sibling with ChargeDescription = 'Leased Outdoor Lighting' - the entire detail node should be ignored that contains the ChargeData element with 'Leased Outdoor Lighting'. 
          )
```

My XSL version is 1.0 if that's of value.

Source XML:

```
    <Source>
      <Detail>
        <ServiceType>electric</ServiceType>
        <Charges>
           <ChargeData>
            <AllowanceChargeInd>C</AllowanceChargeInd>
            <ServiceAmount>19.8</ServiceAmount>
            <ChargeDescription>7% Sales Tax</ChargeDescription>
            <ChargeID>sales_tax</ChargeID>
          </ChargeData>
          <ChargeData>
            <AllowanceChargeInd>C</AllowanceChargeInd>
            <ServiceAmount>282.8</ServiceAmount>
            <ChargeDescription>E-2 Demand</ChargeDescription>
            <ChargeID>usage_charge</ChargeID>
          </ChargeData>
          <ChargeData>
            <AllowanceChargeInd>C</AllowanceChargeInd>
            <ServiceAmount>165.91</ServiceAmount>
            <ChargeDescription>7% Sales Tax</ChargeDescription>
            <ChargeID>sales_tax</ChargeID>
          </ChargeData>
          <ChargeData>
            <AllowanceChargeInd>C</AllowanceChargeInd>
            <ServiceAmount>2370.15</ServiceAmount>
            <ChargeDescription>E-2 Commercial</ChargeDescription>
            <ChargeID>usage_charge</ChargeID>
          </ChargeData>
          <ChargeData>
            <AllowanceChargeInd>C</AllowanceChargeInd>
            <ServiceAmount>2838.66</ServiceAmount>
            <Quantity>0</Quantity>
            <ChargeDescription>subTotal-DistributionCharges</ChargeDescription>
          </ChargeData>
        </Charges>
      </Detail>
      <Detail>
        <ServiceType>electric</ServiceType>
        <Charges>
          <ChargeData>
            <AllowanceChargeInd>C</AllowanceChargeInd>
            <ServiceAmount>2.57</ServiceAmount>
            <ChargeDescription>7% Sales Tax</ChargeDescription>
            <ChargeID>sales_tax</ChargeID>
          </ChargeData>
          <ChargeData>
            <AllowanceChargeInd>C</AllowanceChargeInd>
            <ServiceAmount>36.8</ServiceAmount>
            <ChargeDescription>Leased Outdoor Lighting</ChargeDescription>
            <ChargeID>usage_charge</ChargeID>
          </ChargeData>
          <ChargeData>
            <AllowanceChargeInd>C</AllowanceChargeInd>
            <ServiceAmount>39.37</ServiceAmount>
            <Quantity>0</Quantity>
            <ChargeDescription>subTotal-DistributionCharges</ChargeDescription>
          </ChargeData>
        </Charges>
      </Detail>
    </Source>
```

My xsl, well I've tried multiple and keep hitting a dead-end:

```
    sum(//ChargeData[not(contains(ChargeDescription,'Leased Outdoor Lighting')) 
    and not(contains(Detail/Charges/ChargeData/ChargeDescription, 'subTotal'))  
    and ancestor::Detail/ServiceType='electric']/ServiceAmount)
```

or

```
    sum(//ChargeData[contains(ChargeDescription, 'subTotal-DistributionCharges') 
    and ancestor::Detail/ServiceType='electric']/ServiceAmount)
    -
    sum(//ChargeData[contains(ChargeDescription, 'Leased Outdoor Lighting') 
    and ancestor::Detail/ServiceType='electric']/ServiceAmount)
```

Maybe this isn't possible.  One thing I can't do is change the schema/data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused by your requirements and your sample has mismatched tags (`<Source>` `</Bill>`)

This selects the single ChargeData element in your sample that I think matches your criteria

```
Detail
 [ServiceType="electric"]
 [not(Charges/ChargeData/ChargeDescription[.="Leased Outdoor Lighting"])]
 /Charges/ChargeData[ChargeDescription="subTotal-DistributionCharges"]
```

**Explanation**

- `Detail`
  Select Detail child elements
- `[ServiceType="electric"]`
  Select only the Detail elements with child ServiceType element with a value of "electric"
- `[not(Charges/ChargeData/ChargeDescription[.="Leased Outdoor Lighting"])]`
  Exclude Detail elements where there is a descendent ChargeDescription matching exclusion string provided
- `/Charges/ChargeData[ChargeDescription="subTotal-DistributionCharges"]`
  Beneath the filtered Detail elements, select ChargeData where there is a child ChargeDescription matching string provided

So

```
sum(
 Detail
 [ServiceType="electric"]
 [not(Charges/ChargeData/ChargeDescription[.="Leased Outdoor Lighting"])]
 /Charges/ChargeData[ChargeDescription="subTotal-DistributionCharges"]/ServiceAmount
)
```

Yields

```
2838.6599999999999
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Matt.  I fixed the XML, sorry about that closing tag.

I tried your solution in XML Spy and it doesn't like it.  Tried tweaking it and couldn't get there, but in VS2010 it's a bingo. Someday I might have my head around this syntax. Thank you so much!